# How to use Listview in SingleChildScrollView in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I need to use 3 horizontal ListView in the SingleChildScrollView widget. But nothing is displayed. I use these codes for one of ListViews:

```
Scaffold(
    body: new SingleChildScrollView(
  primary: true,
  child: new Column(
    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
    children: [
      new ListView.builder(
          primary: false,
          shrinkWrap: true,
          physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
          itemCount: _categoryModel.length,
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) => new Card(
            child: new Center(
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10, horizontal: 16),
                child: new Text(_categoryModel[index].title),
              ),
            ),
          ))
    ],
  ),
))
```

How can I fix this error without using the container with a height?

Answer (score 0):

try wrapping your `ListView` with `Expanded`

Answer (score 0):

Use This :

```
 Scaffold(
        body: new SingleChildScrollView(
      
      child: new Container(
        child:      new ListView.builder(
              primary: false,
              shrinkWrap: true,
              physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
              itemCount: _categoryModel.length,
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) => new Card(
                child: new Center(
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10, horizontal: 16),
                    child: new Text(_categoryModel[index].title),
                  ),
                ),
              ))
       
      ),
    ))
```

Comment: Remove primary from singleChildScrollview

Answer (score 0):

Use Wrap widget instead of ListView.